# Problems with Master Page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

What i need use to render a widget without use contentplaceholder??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the widget as a partial view and rendering it on the Master Page with:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("YourWidgetViewNameHere"); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i solve this problem with RenderAction(), and im very impressed with this exists in harmony talking about widgets the RenderAction is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ContentPlaceHolder in master page then you can just create normal View as a standalone page.